# VBA Method doesn't run due to invocation error

Tags: excel, vba, methods

Hello I am running a VBA script in excel 365, and am trying to make an object (day) store a list of custom objects (job) but when trying to input the array of objects I run into an error.

I am using Property handlers to access the private internal array for the day object.

This is how it gets ran, the jobTest function only creates some arbitrary job objects.

```
Sub dayTest()
jobTest
Debug.Print testJob.GNum
Dim foo As New day
foo.DateBlock = DateValue("14 / 03 / 2020")
Debug.Print TypeName(testJob)
Dim x As Variant
x = foo.JobsForDay(0, testJob)
End Sub
```

When running this code I get the error:

```
Wrong number of arguments or property assignment
```

But when looking at my access methods I created, these don't seem to apply.

```
Private mDateStored As Date
Private mNumJobs As Long
Private mJobsForDay() As job

Property Get JobsForDay(val As Long) As Variant
    JobsForDay = mJobsForDay(val)
End Property

Property Let JobsForDay(val As Long, jobObj As Variant)
    mNumJobs = mNumJobs + 1
    ReDim Preserve mJobsForDay(mNumJobs)

    mJobsForDay(val) = jobObj
End Property
```

I am trying to call the Let function, however the compiler throws a generic "Expected =" error when I run the code as

```
foo.JobsForDay(0, testJob)
```

Which is why I have the variant x accepting all input from the method.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This line of code `x = foo.JobsForDay(0, testJob)` is calling Property Get which doesn't take 2 arguments.

Comment: I figured but so how do I call the Let property? Because when I just have     foo.JobsForDay(0, testJob), I get the error "Expected ="

Comment: Two things. First, If `mJobsForDay` is an array of objects, you'll want a `Set` property procedure, not a `Let` property procedure. This way you can `Set` array elements to the given object. Second, if you're controlling a dynamically sized array within your class object, you'll have a much easier time if you create an `AddItem` procedure. This way your `Set` or `Let` statement doesn't need to specify index, which avoids the "Array Out of Bounds" error when trying to access an array element that doesn't exist yet (because you're trying to add it)

Comment: You can either say `Set x = foo.JobsForDay(0)` or `Set foo.JobsForDay(0) = testJob`.  Although as mentioned by @Toddleson you will need to change the Property Let to Property `Set`.  Also, instead of using Variants in the properties use `job`.